# Numpy import error Python3 on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

When I try to import numpy in Python3 i get an error.
I installed it via pip3 and it got installed succesfully.

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Here is the error message when i try to import numpy:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You're missing a core dependency of numpy. Does running `sudo apt-get install python-dev libatlas-base-dev` fix the problem? If that doesn't work, you can try installing RPi specific versions of numpy, see comments here: https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/86dwpz/cant_install_numpy_through_pip3/dw4ycqx

Comment: @BillDeRose your solution needs to rank higher in google search. thanks!

Comment: DON'T USE SUDO WITH PIP!

Comment: @ComputerScientist It is sometimes ok to pip with sudo, if you want to install some(trusted) package globally. On Raspberry Pi space is generally limited and you won't want to waste it by creating a `venv` or similar.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer because it seemed helpful to a few users.

You are missing a core `numpy` dependency. Running

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libatlas-base-dev
```

should fix the problem.

If that doesn't work, you can try installing RPi specific versions of `numpy`, see comments [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/86dwpz/cant_install_numpy_through_pip3/dw4ycqx/).

Comment: Thanks, it also fixed my problem with importing scipy error

Comment: Heads up for some (RPi 4) users - this broke stuff, setting the default python version back to 2.7.18.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to add an answer as I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I had this issue on my Raspberry Pi 4.

In my case this was fixed simply by running this in the command line:

```shell
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

I thought initially I was missing a python module dependency, but this is a unix dependency, its shouldn't affect you python virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libatlas-base-dev` did not work for me.

Installing `numpy==1.15.1` did.